how to mint nft with metadata in solana reactjs javascript
import { createUmi, signerIdentity, generateSigner, createSignerFromKeypair } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import { mplTokenMetadata, createAndMint, TokenStandard } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";
import { base58 } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi/serializers";
import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";

 const MintNFT = async () => {
        // Connect to the Solana Devnet
        const umi = createUmi('https://soft-late-tent.solana-devnet.quiknode.pro/07a90297e0945453e902ac44beae4efbffb4bafb/');
    
    // Deserialize the secret key
    const uintKey = base58.deserialize("3XMuQJU9TDfdTz5wow1hrM4y7XvJ5odZSwWoW23Wodf2KsG6SYC3LSbDj4NEZqWwwWovGCSo6UV6HKpBojkWpb7");

    // Create a Keypair from the deserialized secret key
    const userWallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(uintKey));

    // Create a signer from the keypair
    const userWalletSigner = createSignerFromKeypair(umi, userWallet);
    
    // Generate a new signer for minting
    const mint = generateSigner(umi);
    
    // Use the wallet signer and token metadata plugins
    umi.use(signerIdentity(userWalletSigner));
    umi.use(mplTokenMetadata());
    
    // Mint the NFT
    createAndMint(umi, {
      mint,
      authority: umi.identity,
      name: 'VanthuruDaPulla',
      uri: 'https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmSD4dtfZCyaxZW1eiX7jyfUrUJ43jj8bS559FCVij7ePq/tokenname46_soulbound_camino_5.txt',
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(500),
      tokenOwner: userWallet.publicKey,
      tokenStandard: TokenStandard.NonFungible,
    })
      .sendAndConfirm(umi)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Successfully minted NFT:', mint.publicKey);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error minting NFT:', err);
      });
};

this my npm version
"@metaplex-foundation/js": "^0.20.1",
"@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata": "^3.2.1",
"@metaplex-foundation/umi": "^0.9.2",
"@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults": "^0.9.2",
"@metaplex/js": "^4.12.0",
"@project-serum/anchor": "^0.26.0",
"@solana-mobile/wallet-adapter-mobile": "^2.1.3",
"@solana/spl-token": "^0.4.6",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.9.4",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "^0.15.21",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "^0.9.5",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-walletconnect": "^0.1.16",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.16.0",
"@solana/web3.js": "^1.36.0",

when i install this @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata i am facing error
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at ./node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/dist/src/errors.js 

can any one help me to resolve this i need to mintnft with meta data in reactjs javascript in solana using private key

This question is similar to: how to mint nfts with metadata in reactjs javascript. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
